# how to find differential of trigonomic function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the differential of $\sin^4(\pi x)$.

This was one I got stumped on. $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin^4(\pi x)$. Would you split up the $\sin^4(x)$ into $\sin^2(x)$ and then split up into pythag identities and go from there? $(1-cos^2(x))$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you re-type your question? You want to find the derivative of $\sin^4(\pi x)$? If yes, you can just apply the chain rule

Comment: That's exactly what I need to know! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Differentiate using the [chain rule](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/ChainRule.aspx) .
$$\sin^4\pi x=(\sin\pi x)^4\\\frac{dy}{dx} (\sin\pi x)^4=4(\sin\pi x)^3\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}(\sin\pi x)$$

Comment: thank you for setting it up. i went from there and ended up with 4picos(pix)sin^3(pix)

Comment: Yes, that's the answer!